# Are there polar plots and airfoil data points available for the RAF4?

Tags: aerodynamics

Are there polar plots and airfoil data points available for the RAF4?

I understand this is the airfoil used for the horizontal stabilizer of the Zenith 701, which should be similar to a NACA4412 airfoil.

Comment: Are you sure of the name RAF4?  I find no mention of it, nevermind its properties, in the usual compendiums of airfoils.  Even the Mighty G finds little after 1918.